# Why the letter $B$ for magnetic fields?

Tags: soft-question, magnetic-fields, history, notation

Is there a reason behind the usage of this letter to represent magnetic fields, or is it a randomly made choice?

Comment: If I recall correctly it is due to Maxwell, who chose alphabetically all the way up to F or H, not all of which are currently in use.

Comment: Such notational soft-questions appear to be off-topic, cf. e.g. [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1083/2451) meta post. You may try chat instead.

Comment: @Qmechanic : Maxwell used the notations $B,C,D$ for the $3$ components of the magnetic field and $E,F,G$ for the $3$ components of the electric field. The followers decided to use $B$ to represent the magnetic field as a whole and $E$ to represent the electric field as a whole.

Comment: that's curious, I always thought that E came from electric. thanks for the answer!